# NodeJS and Express: Express router not calling the correct route

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I am trying to call my getAssignments route but for some reason when I run it on postman it is calling my getStudent route. What I am calling on Postman - localhost:5000/api/assignments

```
//server.js file
app.use("/api/", studentRouter);
app.use("/api/", assignmentRouter);

//student.router.js file
router.get("/student", auth, getStudent);

//assignment.router.js file
router.get("/assignments", auth, getAssignments);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
app.use("/", assignmentRouter);
router.get("/api/assignments", auth, getAssignments);
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you. But why is that the case?